# How to access a single object from a JSON array

Tags: angularjs, json

Okay so I have a JSON:

```
{
  "Concepts": [
    {
      "Concept": "1",
      "Description": "siopao"
    },
    {
      "Concept": "4",
      "Description": "gulaman"
    },
    {
      "Concept": "9",
      "Description": "sisig"
    },
    {
      "Concept": "12",
      "Description": "noodle"
    },
    {
      "Concept": "15",
      "Description": "sisigan"
    },
    {
      "Concept": "16",
      "Description": "buko shake"
    },
    {
      "Concept": "17",
      "Description": "mango shake"
    },
    {
      "Concept": "19",
      "Description": "burger"
    },
    {
      "Concept": "20",
      "Description": "sample"
    },
    {
      "Concept": "21",
      "Description": "shit"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I get only "Description":"siopao"? I'm using AngularJS.

Comment: This would be a good time to read through [ask]. You haven't provided nearly enough detail in the question

Answer (score 2):

**If you want to map the jsonstring to something like:**

```
["siopao", "gulaman", "sisig", "noodle", "sisigan", "buko shake", "mango shake", "burger", "sample", "shit"]
```

**use**

```
var object = JSON.parse(jsonString);
var descriptions = object.Concepts.map(function(c) {
     return o.Description;
});
```

If you only want the one with the description **"siopao"**, add a filter before the map:

```
var object = JSON.parse(jsonString);
var description = object.Concepts.filter(function(a) {
     return a.Description === "siopao";
}).map(function(c) {
     return o.Description;
})[0];
```